# Is my site secure? It has an SSL certificate installed but no lock on the addressbar

Tags: html, ssl

I have just bought an `SSL` certificate and with a great deal of help from my host service installed it on my website. My hosts assure me that it is now secure and that data to and from the site is encrypted.

However I am not a little confused. All redirection within the site is now set to **https://** but if I manually put in the same page using **http://** it also works. Is this a problem?

Also, no lock appears at the end of the address bar as it seems to do with other secure sites. Should there be?

[image]

Comment: The browser's show locked/golden/awesome SSL status only from recognized CA signers.  From whom did you purchase your SSL cert?

Comment: Thanks - I wondered if that was the case. Mine is a cheap one from PositiveSSL .... say no more.

Comment: Cheap and free are fine.  It is still securing the protocol but it won't give the client's/browser's a warm fuzzy feeling without the CA doing some additional verification of who you are.

Comment: I posted it as an answer because I don't like seeing posts in the 'unanswered' category simply because the answer is a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each browser/device have a list of recognized Certificate Authorities (CA) that they know and trust.  SSL certs from these providers will often display the additional security icons like the lock or the green bar in Chrome.  The list is long and varies by browser as you'd expect.  This is [Mozilla's lis](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/governance/policies/security-group/certs/included/)t, for example.

Typically getting that type of SSL cert is more pricey and comes with an additional step of identity verification.

In your case the lock is not showing but the SSL keys have been installed and configured which means you still ARE secure.  (Otherwise you'd get a warning about the SSL cert not matching the domain which lets the user know it may be fake or is at least questionable)  As long as you aren't seeing that message you can rest easy that it's at least secure.  The browsers just won't go out of their way to show the extra "bling".

As far as your redirect.  If you still have something listening at :80 it will work with http as well.  If you are trying to force it all to the https version then your rewrite rule may need a little work if you are still able to access it via http.  But http and https can co-exist just fine and often do (like a regular http site that doesn't go https until you enter the checkout process)  For an API-type of service, or if you are trying to use something like SPDY, you probably want to force everything to use the https protocol instead.

Comment: A really good answer - thank you very much. Extremely helpful and reassuring.